# При вставке кирилических символов ошибка - ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: c#, sql, кодировка, oracle, insert

Имеется файл, с которого считываются данные и они же добавляются в БД Oracle.

Проблема на примере:

- Поле `VARCHAR2`, размером 3 байта
- Пытаемся вставить туда 'абв' и тут же ловим exception:

  > value too large for column (actual: 6, maximum: 3)

Т.е., каждый символ кодируется двумя байтами. Окей, подумал я, сейчас перекодируем. В БД стоит кодировка `AL32UTF8`. Кодировка файла - `CP866`.

Попытка безуспешной перекодировки:

```
Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(s);
byte[] convertedByteString = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
s = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);
```

Изменять тип колонок нельзя. Каким образом можно решить эту проблему? Возможно ли как-то явно указать кодировку добавляемого значения при вставке данных в БД?

Comment: *Возможно ли как-то явно указать кодировку добавляемого значения при вставке данных в БД?* CONVERT(), https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm#SQLRF00620

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать псевдокод запроса на вставку с использованием функции CONVERT?

Comment: Если кодировка сессии не отличается от кодировки хранения БД то оракл ничего сам конвертировать не будет. и значение вставится как есть (при условии, что на клиенте вы его то же никак не конвертируете и оставляете в 866) после чего значение из БД сможет прочитать то же точно так же криво настроенный клиент и получит он его разумеется в 866

Comment: И абсолютно не понятно, почему нельзя менять колонку. varchar2(3) при кодировке БД utf-8 в принципе может хранить только полтора символа, что мягко говоря странно. явная ошибка проектирования БД

Comment: На самом деле в вопросе показана суть проблемы. В реальности множество полей имеют размеры 10-300 byte. Какие-то значения из файла вписываются в это, какие-то нет. Менять нельзя, потому что начальник строго запретил :)

Comment: Надо заменить семантику строчных полей с `byte` на `char`.  Это не изменение типа колонки, она будет выглядеть - `mycol varchar2(3 char)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение, изменить семантику длины полей, в которых предпологается хранить информацию с не ASCII символами.

В примерах используются юникоды:
 `\0430\0431\0432 = абв = 160,161,162 в CP866 или 208,176,208,177,208,178 в UTF8`

```
host chcp
Active code page: 866

@[%nls_lang%]
SP2-0310: unable to open file "[.RU8PC866]"
--кодовые страницы ОС и ДБ сессии клиента совпадают

alter table tstcp866 modify (code varchar2(3 char));

Table altered.

insert into tstcp866 values ('абв');

1 row created.

select code, dump(code) dc from tstcp866;

COD DC
--- -----------------------------------------------
абв Typ=1 Len=6: 208,176,208,177,208,178
```

Таким образом, в поле длиной 3-и символа, поместились 6-ь байт. Никаких проблем с запросами с этим полем, ни с других клиентов, ни на уровне БД, не будет.

### Не рекомендуемое решение

Можно вставить в те же 3-и байта и без изменений в БД, но это так же, как полторашку по двум поллитровкам разливать.

Для сохранения кодировки источника, кодовая странница клиента должна быть такой же, как и БД. В этом случае не будет происходить неявнаое конвертирование данных. Т.е. установите окружение клиента `set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` (или в реестре), и данные будут загружены в БД как есть в CP866.

```
host chcp
Active code page: 866

select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8

@[%nls_lang%]
SP2-0310: unable to open file "[.AL32UTF8]"

create table tstcp866 (code varchar2(3));

insert into tstcp866 values ('абв');

1 row created.

select code, dump(code) dc from tstcp866;
COD DC
--- -----------------------------------------------
абв Typ=1 Len=3: 160,161,162
```

Результат вроде достигнут, но в поле не валидные юникоды. Как сложно должен выглядеть запрос на уровне БД, чтобы перекодировать поле:

```
select convert(code, 'AL32UTF8', 'RU8PC866') code
from tstcp866 
where convert(code, 'AL32UTF8', 'RU8PC866')=to_nchar(unistr('\0430\0431\0432'))
;
CODE
---------------
абв
```

Ещё раз, этот хак не рекомендуется, т.к. доступ только с клиента с "неправильно" установленной кодировкой. В худшем случае, например, при неявном конвертировании, произойдёт потеря данных.